# Загрузчик изображений

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте! Посоветуйте какой-нибудь хороший загрузчик изображений (массовый) с дальнейшим добавлением в БД. Подкиньте что-нибудь. Желательно по такому описанию. Прочитать туториал какой-нибудь или что-то  тп. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отличный плагин jQuery-File-Upload ([Демо](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/), [Скачать](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload), [Почитать про него на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140400/)). Сам им пользуюсь. Немного тяжеловат, но если это принципиально, то несложно убрать все лишнее.

---

ПО поводу инсерта в базу. Я решил данную проблему в лоб. Картинки уже лежат у нас на сервере, т.е. в БД мне нужно сохранять только пути к ним. Как видно в коде, после загрузки файлов на сервер у нас генерится следующий хтмл код:

```
<a href="..." title="..." rel="gallery" download="...">...</a>
```

Как видим все ссылки имеют аттрибут rel="gallery", с его помощью мы можем и собирать все пути (jquery):

```
$("[rel='gallery']").each(function(){
   files += (files==''?'':';') + $(this).attr('href');
});
```

В итоге получим строку ссылок, разделенных "**;**" которую я и записываю в БД. При выводе просто разделяю строку в массив по символу "**;**" и вывожу ссылки на файлы.

Решение примитивное, но надеюсь оно вам поможет.

Comment: Спасибо,меня он очень устраивает я даже пробовал с ним разобраться только подскажите пожалуйста как занести данные в базу об апплоуде ?А конкретно одно данно с страницы откуда был аплоуд,ну и данные ссессии,куда нужно вставить код с insert ,ну и при нажатии на кнопку удаления код с delit из таблицы ?Второй день мучаюсь с ним,от отчаяния тут написал1Помогите пожалуйста,как совместить его с базой ?Очень нужно.

Comment: Подскажите вы сталкивались с такой проблемой ?Можете объяснить как можно сделать это в скрипте обработчике файлов загруженных ?